# asp classic retrieve and display single recordset

Tags: asp-classic

i hv a code that need me to find only a single line of recordset from the database into the variable.

```
dim Connect,conn_,data,sql

Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open "toServer"
sql = "SELECT * from sppro where proj_name='pname'"
set Data = Connect.Execute(sql)

response.write data("proj_id")
```

i just cant find to correct way to retrieve and view single record set... i found something about cursor, but i dont understand it at all...
can anyone pls explain to me?

edit:

error tht i got with this code is as below.

ADODB.Field error '80020009'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

/bkpi-msn/Include/ServerSideAjax.asp, line 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you already know how to display one record from a database, but now you want to display more than one record. Is that right?

With some changes to your code, you can loop though all records:

```
dim Connect,conn_,data,sql

Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open "toServer"
sql = "SELECT * from sppro where proj_name='pname'"
set Data = Connect.Execute(sql)

Do Until Data.Eof

    response.write data("proj_id")

    Data.MoveNext
Loop
```

Edit: to retrieve just one row, you can use the following. It's basically the same, except there is a check to ensure there is at least one record, and no need to loop through the recordset.

```
dim Connect,conn_,data,sql

Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open "toServer"
sql = "SELECT * from sppro where proj_name='pname'"
set Data = Connect.Execute(sql)

If Not Data.Eof Then

    response.write data("proj_id")

End If
```

Comment: actually it reverse. i know how to display many record. i dont know how to display just one record. when i do as tht above, i got error..

Comment: I edited the answer with code for accessing a single record. The multi record code should still have worked. If you get any errors please let us know what the error was and on what line.

Comment: Maybe the SQL query is not returning any data. Have you tried running the query some other way such as using SQL Management Studio (if it is a SQL Server database)? What type of database is it?

Comment: mysql database. it will return data and view it perfectly if my query just `"select * from sppro"`. i think the problem is when i query like this "`select * from sppro where proj_id='pname'` , it will actually got one row of record, since the id was unique..

Comment: Is pname an actual value from the database or a variable that contains the value? If it's a variable then you will have to change the sql query line to: `sql = "SELECT * from sppro where proj_name='" & pname & "'"` (but you should protect against sql injection too).